# Heroku App crashed it is not dynos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

**The error I'm getting:**

Application Error

```
    An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try         again in a few moments.

    If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

**Therefore I checked the logs and get this unhelpfull:**

```
2013-07-23T19:49:41.457624+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rankthisuptest1.herokuapp.com fwd="190.3.13.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

**About the app**

This is a simple, example app as I'm new to Ruby on Rails. But things I think I tested for:

1) I am using the correct sql:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
end
```

2) I am bundling with production (I was bundling without production at first that might have been the cause of the problem but now I changed that), running the bundle in --without test.

Maybe is a problem with the routes?

Any suggestion will do, thanks!

Comment: There should be something more in log, if not do `heroku ps:restart` and check again.

Comment: And what do you mean by "it is not dynos", that there are NO dynos? What is result of `heroku ps`?

Comment: does the app run locally? please add more of the log, something like the snippet here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed

Comment: Sorry for not addying the complete log. Thanks for the response I managed to solve it myself.

Comment: Can you put a solution, so we know as well?

Comment: It's been 7 years. I don't remember